# MainActivity to Fragment and from that Fragment back to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

[Solve by using getActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283344/mainactivity-to-fragment-and-from-that-fragment-back-to-mainactivity/31284973#31284973)
I have this MainActivity.java and RepeatEntry.java

inside my MainActivity i have this code to have RepeatEntry ui

```
//i did hide two linear layout here with buttons and edittext inside it ,using the following method 
 hideTwoLinearLayout();
 showCategoryContainerLayout();
Fragment fragment = new RepeatEntry();
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  //category_cont is a linear layout container for my fragment
 ft.replace(R.id.category_cont, fragment);
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 ft.commit();
```

inside my RepeatEntry.java sample code

```
Button k = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        k.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
               // startActivity(intent);

               // if i use popBackStack and also remove the code for intent , i cannot show what i hide  
//note i have a method inside mainactivity to showTwoLinearLayout()
               getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
```

Now my question is, **do i have other option other than using intent to go back to MainActivity view**

**Note:Edited**

Comment: No, you  need an intent to start an activity

Comment: You never left MainActivity, a fragment runs inside an activity.  The answer below, for instance, shows a method to remove the fragment from the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any way i solve my problem just in case if anyone might see this.I came up with two solution which i think the first one is best for me.Thanks to Adnan Basar who give me idea.

**First solution** is so simple  by just adding this code inside my onClick event

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).showTwoLinearLayout();
((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideCategoryContainerLayout();
```

**Second Solution** I created `Activity` after `extends Fragment{`

```
Activity mainActivity;
```

And use override methods

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mainActivity= activity;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // this is where i call the method for showing the twolinearlayout again  
          ((MainActivity) mainActivity).showTwoLinearLayout();
          ((MainActivity) mainActivity).hideCategoryContainerLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the transaction to backstack and then reverse with poping the backstack the code is here

```
 Fragment fragment = new RepeatEntry();
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  //category_cont is a linear layout container for my fragment
 ft.replace(R.id.category_cont, fragment).addToBackStack("tag");
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 ft.commit();
```

And for going back to the activity view call this to pop backstack

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack();
```

Also you can use the tag to poping back the specific transaction with

```
fm.popBackStack("tag");
```

Comment: Now the fragment is gone but a problem exist sir :(

Comment: oh my God.when i go to the fragment i hide some views in the activity and show the category_cont containerr for the fragment and when im in the fragment i use popBackStack to hide the fragment , the result is i cannot show what i hide during the event in showing the fragment

Comment: you doesn't need to hide anything the fragment will replace the container automatically and after poping backstack the views will apear automatically which was removed by the fragment

Comment: dont create intent and start the activity
remove the code on button click which is starting activity again

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called *onAttach* in your fragment. You can write an interface and assign your fragment's activity like:

```
private MyFragmentListener mListener;


@Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mListener = ((MainActivity) activity);
}

public interface MyFragmentListener{ 
  void onClicked(int value);
}

//Call your listener when button clicked or other events
... mListener.onClicked(position);
```

Or another solution is to use Otto or Eventbus to get rid unnecessary code

Comment: thanks sir you give me idea :) so one vote for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also go back in Fragment like

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();